# Barcode scan on picture from gallery

Tags: android, zxing, barcode-scanner

A little idea about what I want to achieve in steps:

1. Either take an image from camera or choose picture from gallery
2. Load the result image in an `ImageView` (possibly)

Now here between step 1 and step 2, I want to scan barcode on the image from step 1.

Based on the result of scan :

- if sucessful, show a `Toast` with barcode informations like it's format and content.
- if not, show a `Toast` telling that the image doesn't have any barcode.

I explored ZXing (to some extent) to meet my goal.

But what I couldn't get is:

1. How to scan barcode on picture from gallery?
2. How to return a picture after successful barcode scan with the content and format information?

Answer (score 1):

I finally got a way to get it working with zxing barcode scanner library.

Few things to keep in mind while getting image from any saved gallery or folder,

- the image should be of good quality.
- Image should not be rotated.(It causes problem sometimes).
- And last , make sure barcode you scanning is supported by zxing barcode scanner.

Here is the code.

```
try {
         Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(MyActivity.this.getResources(),
         R.drawable.barcode_dummy /* ANY DUMMY IMAGE WITH BARCODE */);

        int[] intArray = new int[bMap.getWidth() * bMap.getHeight()];
        // copy pixel data from the Bitmap into the 'intArray' array
        bMap.getPixels(intArray, 0, bMap.getWidth(), 0, 0, bMap.getWidth(),
                bMap.getHeight());

        LuminanceSource source = new RGBLuminanceSource(bMap.getWidth(),
                bMap.getHeight(), intArray);
        BinaryBitmap bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source));

        Reader reader = new MultiFormatReader();// use this otherwise
                                                // ChecksumException
        try {
            Hashtable<DecodeHintType, Object> decodeHints = new Hashtable<DecodeHintType, Object>();
            decodeHints.put(DecodeHintType.TRY_HARDER, Boolean.TRUE);
            decodeHints.put(DecodeHintType.PURE_BARCODE, Boolean.TRUE);

            Result result = reader.decode(bitmap, decodeHints);
                Utility.ShowToastShort(MyActivity.this,
                        result.getText());

        } catch (NotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ChecksumException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (FormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Hope it helps. It worked for me. Thanks